# ¿Cómo retornar SESSION con datos de un archivo XML?

Tags: php, xml

Se están generando facturas y guardando en `XML` la misma que se pueden guardar en borrador para más adelante enviar o editar y la incógnita o el problema es cuando el usuario trate de editar esté borrador en otras palabras dicho archivo `file.xml`.

No sé están guardando los productos agregados al carrito de la compra en la base de datos, solo por medio de `SESSION`. Normalmente se agregan al carrito de compra de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="text" name="qtyupdate[24][Normal][Normal]" value="2">
```

Mediante`PHP` se puede hacer prácticamente todo, desde convertir un archivo `.xml` a `json`, `array` entre otros, por lo tanto de la siguiente información del archivo `XML`:

```
<detalle> 
<codigoPrincipal>694605120074</codigoPrincipal>
<descripcion>ACETONA YM 180ML</descripcion>
<cantidad>1</cantidad>
<precioUnitario>3.00</precioUnitario>
<descuento>0.00</descuento> <precioTotalSinImpuesto>3.00</precioTotal SinImpuesto>
<impuestos>
<impuesto>
<codigo>2</codigo>    
<codigoPorcentaje>2</codigoPorcentaje>
<tarifa>12</tarifa>
<baseImponible>3.00</baseImponible>
<valor>0.36</valor>
</impuesto>
</impuestos>
</detalle>
```

Se necesita los datos de `<codigoPrincipal>` y `<cantidad>`

Esto se puede obtener mediante la siguiente manera:

```
$data=simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$data->item->codigoPrincipal;
```

De la información del código principal, se necesita realizar una consulta a la tabla `tbl_products` pasando como condición `$data->item->codigoPrincipal;` para obtener el `id` del producto para posteriormente enviar automáticamene está información:

```
<input type="text" name="qtyupdate[24][Normal][Normal]" value="2">
```

Pero desde `PHP`, ¿Aquí no se cómo se podría enviar sin el `form` o `input` estos datos para que aparezcan en el carrito de compra?

La `SESSION` del carrito espera recibir o de la siguiente manera funciona:

```
if (isset($_POST) OR 
isset($_POST['addCart'])) {
    //Array ( [1] => Array ( [Black] => Array ( [XL] => 1 ) ) )
    //Array ( [1] => Array ( [color-blue] => Array( [L] => ) )) 

$attributes = (isset($_POST['qtyupdate']) &&  is_array($_POST['qtyupdate'])) ? $_POST['qtyupdate'] : array(); 

//print_r($attributes); 

$itemId = isset($_POST['itemId']) ? 
$_POST['itemId'] : "";
$item_color = isset($_POST['color']) ? $_POST['color'] : "Normal";
$item_size = isset($_POST['size']) ? $_POST['size'] : "Normal";
$qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ? intval($_POST['qty']) : 1; 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_POST['qtyupdate'])) {
```

En conclusión necesito una simulación de `form` pero en `PHP` para poder enviar todos los productos que existan en el archivo `.xml` a la SESSION del carrito, es decir de esto:

```
<input type="text" name="qtyupdate[24][Normal][Normal]" value="2">
```

Algo en PHP que execute esos datos para que se creen la SESSION de esos productos al carro de compra. ¿Esto es posible?

> Recordar que pueden existir varios productos en el archivo `xml`.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Si los datos están en un archivo `.xml` entonces abre ese archivo y lee los datos que tiene. Si no es eso, explícanos dónde están los datos que quieres leer. El planteamiento es muy confuso, creo que se pierde en detalles innecesarios.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si amigo, se debe leer los datos del archivo `xml` algo así `$data=simplexml_load_file('file.xml');`

Comment: @A.Cedano Obtener las dos información que mencioné, realizar la consulta para obtener el ID del producto. Y poder generar la SESSION de esos productos al carro de la compra, lo que no si es posible reemplazar esto: `<input type="text" qtyupdate[24][Normal][Normal]" value="2">` solo con código `PHP` para retornar la SESSION automáticamente

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿Porqué automáticamente?, por el motivo de que se supone que el usuario está editando una factura guardada entonces no es correcto tener que buscar los productos y agregarlos mediante un `form` `input` entonces por eso estoy tratando de que al momento de editar dicho archivo retorne esos productos a la `SESSION` del carro de compra.

Comment: Es que no se entiende. Pulsa en [edit] y explica el contexto de la forma más sencilla posible. *Tengo estos datos en tal parte, estos otros datos en tal otra parte. Con esos datos quiero hacer tal cosa, obteniendo tal resultado final. Para lograrlo tengo este código, pero no funciona, da error en tal parte. Arroja esto, pero lo que espero obtener es esto.*

Comment: @A.Cedano En conclusión como puedo enviar esto: `<input type="text" qtyupdate[24][Normal][Normal]" value="2">` sin `form` sin `input` solo con `PHP` automáticamente esos datos al archivo del código php que me agrega los productos al carro de compras, es posible esto?

Comment: @A.Cedano Solo necesito saber eso, lo otro como he mencionado en la pregunta puedo obtener la información, puedo hacer la consulta, solo me falta ese detalle.

Comment: Entiendo. Ahora dinos: ¿qué es `<input type="text" qtyupdate[24][Normal][Normal]" value="2">`y de dónde viene eso? ¿Es una información que el usuario escribe, o es una información que ya existe en alguna parte?

Comment: @A.Cedano Esa información viene desde cada producto del botón `[añadir]` aquí imagen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2DCL.jpg

Comment: @A.Cedano Como se observa la imagen esa es la manera normal de como se agrega los productos al carrito. Pero el archivo xml ya tiene productos guardado por el usuario esos productos lo quiero volver a retornar a la SESSION al momento que le dé en editar, por esa misma información que tiene el campo `input` la quiero enviar automáticamene a PHP, como ya lo explique.

Comment: Ya, pero dices que quieres prescindir del `form`, ¿por qué quieres prescindir de él? En todo caso, creo que lo que necesitas es Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript, para pasar datos entre cliente y servidor. Así, vía Ajax o Fetch puedes pasar los datos de ese formulario al servidor y modificar allí lo que haya que modificar, los datos de la sesión o el xml.

Comment: @A.Cedano Yo digo que no usarlo porque yo quiero que los datos se pasen a la SESSION automáticamente al momento que el usuario de clic en editar el archivo `xml` esa parte no entiendo o si es necesario usar `Ajax` está bien siempre en cuando el usuario no tenga que añadír manualmente nuevamente cada producto que el ya tiene guardado en el archivo `xml`

Comment: Si tú usas Ajax, puedes modificar el `.xml` (que estará en el servidor) cuando quieras o como quieras, es más, sin la necesidad de usar variables de sesión. Desde Ajax tú puedes comunicar entre cliente y servidor directamente, sea en cada cambio de un elemento del formulario, sea al pulsar un botón que recoja todo lo agregado en ese momento en el formulario.

Comment: @A.Cedano Amigo es que la idea no es editar el archivo `xml` si fuera así sería más sencillo, pero pasa que si el usuario desea agregar más productos entonces por eso no me sirve en sí, editar el archivo `xml` por eso necesito procesar los datos del archivo `xml` para luego reemplazar ese archivo con los nuevos cambios que haya realizado el usuario.

Comment: Puse el ejemplo del archivo xml, pero puede ser cualquier otra fuente: variable de sesión, base de datos, etc. La cuestión aquí es que no queda claro lo que quieres hacer y eso dificulta la solución del problema. Supongo que en el cliente tienes un formulario donde el usuario agregará productos y que hay un botón para enviar esos datos al servidor. Si usas Ajax mandas esos datos y los procesas / guardas / añades en el servidor, sin importar la fuente de datos: xml, variable de sesión, base de datos.